# Rewinding qgis._core.QgsFeatureIterator

Tags: pyqgis

How to use [qgis._core.QgsFeatureIterator.rewind()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.20/core/QgsFeatureIterator.html#qgis.core.QgsFeatureIterator.rewind) correctly?

Executing `features.rewind()` returns `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the developers' discussion [here](https://qgis-developer.qgis.narkive.com/bkbR1r2N/how-can-i-reset-the-starting-point-of-a-qgsfeatureiterator):

> When the iterator has given back all the features it gets closed.
> Rewind works only while the iterator is open, so it's supposed to work
> while you're stepping through the iteration. I fear you have to obtain
> a new iterator to repreat the iteration.

Here is an example of how to use the rewind() function:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print(layer)
max_features = layer.featureCount()
print(f'max_features={max_features}')
features = layer.getFeatures()
print(f'type(features)={type(features)}')

for iteration in range(1,3):
    print(f'\nIteration {iteration} features.isClosed()={features.isClosed()}')
    for num, feature in enumerate(features):
        print(num, feature['id'])
        if num==max_features-1:
            features.rewind()
            break

print(f'\nIteration LAST features.isClosed()={features.isClosed()}')
for num, feature in enumerate(features):
    print(num, feature['id'])
print(f'features.isClosed()={features.isClosed()}')
```

The output is:

```py
<QgsVectorLayer: '10 Landsat 8' (postgres)>
max_features=8
type(features)=<class 'qgis._core.QgsFeatureIterator'>

Iteration 1 features.isClosed()=False
0 135394
1 138891
2 138892
3 138893
4 138894
5 138974
6 138975
7 138976

Iteration 2 features.isClosed()=False
0 135394
1 138891
2 138892
3 138893
4 138894
5 138974
6 138975
7 138976

Iteration LAST features.isClosed()=False
0 135394
1 138891
2 138892
3 138893
4 138894
5 138974
6 138975
7 138976
features.isClosed()=True
```